# Tracking model translation progress with Forge Webhooks API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-webhooks

I want to use Webhooks API to track the progress of my model translation (Model Derivative API). So I've posted a Webhook with the event "extraction.updated", as described here : https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/extraction.updated/

It works, but :

1. I receive duplicate callbacks, the first ones contain `hook.hookAttribute : null` in the payload, the others don't have it. Why ?
2. I put the second ones apart, and now I get this :

`extraction updated : success : 99% - progress : 99% complete
extraction updated : success : 99% - progress : 99% complete
extraction updated : success : 8% - progress : 0% complete
extraction updated : success : 8% - progress : 0% complete
extraction updated : success : 8% - progress : 0% complete
extraction updated : success : 8% - progress : 5% complete
extraction updated : success : 8% - progress : 18% complete
extraction updated : success : 8% - progress : 5% complete
extraction updated : success : 9% - progress : 18% complete
extraction updated : success : 9% - progress : 19% complete
extraction updated : success : 12% - progress : 21% complete
extraction updated : success : 8% - progress : 18% complete
extraction updated : success : 11% - progress : 20% complete
extraction updated : success : 11% - progress : 20% complete
extraction updated : success : 12% - progress : 21% complete
extraction updated : success : 14% - progress : 21% complete
extraction updated : success : 12% - progress : 21% complete
extraction updated : success : 16% - progress : 22% complete
extraction updated : success : 12% - progress : 21% complete
extraction updated : success : 12% - progress : 22% complete
extraction updated : success : 17% - progress : 23% complete
extraction updated : success : 17% - progress : 23% complete
extraction updated : success : 14% - progress : 22% complete
extraction updated : success : 17% - progress : 23% complete
extraction updated : success : 17% - progress : 23% complete
extraction updated : success : 16% - progress : 22% complete
extraction updated : success : 14% - progress : 22% complete
extraction updated : success : 17% - progress : 23% complete
extraction updated : success : 17% - progress : 24% complete
extraction updated : success : 16% - progress : 24% complete
extraction updated : success : 19% - progress : 24% complete
extraction updated : success : 16% - progress : 23% complete
extraction updated : success : 19% - progress : 25% complete
extraction updated : success : 20% - progress : 25% complete
extraction updated : success : 19% - progress : 25% complete
extraction updated : success : 22% - progress : 26% complete
extraction updated : success : 22% - progress : 26% complete
extraction updated : success : 20% - progress : 25% complete
extraction updated : success : 20% - progress : 25% complete
extraction updated : success : 20% - progress : 27% complete
extraction updated : success : 20% - progress : 25% complete
extraction updated : success : 22% - progress : 27% complete
extraction updated : success : 19% - progress : 25% complete
extraction updated : success : 20% - progress : 25% complete
extraction updated : success : 20% - progress : 26% complete
extraction updated : success : 24% - progress : 27% complete
extraction updated : success : 20% - progress : 27% complete
extraction updated : success : 25% - progress : 28% complete
extraction updated : success : 25% - progress : 28% complete
extraction updated : success : 25% - progress : 28% complete
extraction updated : success : 25% - progress : 29% complete
extraction updated : success : 25% - progress : 29% complete
extraction updated : success : 27% - progress : 29% complete
extraction updated : success : 25% - progress : 29% complete
extraction updated : success : 25% - progress : 29% complete
extraction updated : success : 29% - progress : 30% complete
extraction updated : success : 27% - progress : 30% complete
extraction updated : success : 29% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 29% - progress : 30% complete
extraction updated : success : 30% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 29% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 30% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 30% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 30% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 27% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 30% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 29% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 30% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 30% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 29% - progress : 31% complete
extraction updated : success : 32% - progress : 32% complete
extraction updated : success : 33% - progress : 32% complete
extraction updated : success : 33% - progress : 32% complete
extraction updated : success : 33% - progress : 33% complete
extraction updated : success : 35% - progress : 34% complete
extraction updated : success : 37% - progress : 34% complete
extraction updated : success : 33% - progress : 33% complete
extraction updated : success : 33% - progress : 34% complete
extraction updated : success : 35% - progress : 34% complete
extraction updated : success : 37% - progress : 35% complete
extraction updated : success : 35% - progress : 34% complete
extraction updated : success : 37% - progress : 35% complete
extraction updated : success : 38% - progress : 35% complete
extraction updated : success : 38% - progress : 36% complete
extraction updated : success : 37% - progress : 36% complete
extraction updated : success : 37% - progress : 35% complete
extraction updated : success : 38% - progress : 35% complete
extraction updated : success : 41% - progress : 37% complete
extraction updated : success : 41% - progress : 37% complete
extraction updated : success : 38% - progress : 36% complete
extraction updated : success : 37% - progress : 36% complete
extraction updated : success : 38% - progress : 36% complete
extraction updated : success : 40% - progress : 36% complete
extraction updated : success : 41% - progress : 37% complete
extraction updated : success : 40% - progress : 37% complete
extraction updated : success : 41% - progress : 38% complete
extraction updated : success : 43% - progress : 38% complete
extraction updated : success : 40% - progress : 37% complete
extraction updated : success : 43% - progress : 39% complete
extraction updated : success : 41% - progress : 38% complete
extraction updated : success : 41% - progress : 38% complete
extraction updated : success : 43% - progress : 38% complete
extraction updated : success : 41% - progress : 38% complete
extraction updated : success : 45% - progress : 39% complete
extraction updated : success : 45% - progress : 39% complete
extraction updated : success : 45% - progress : 39% complete
extraction updated : success : 45% - progress : 40% complete
extraction updated : success : 45% - progress : 40% complete
extraction updated : success : 43% - progress : 40% complete
extraction updated : success : 45% - progress : 40% complete
extraction updated : success : 46% - progress : 40% complete
extraction updated : success : 46% - progress : 40% complete
extraction updated : success : 46% - progress : 41% complete
extraction updated : success : 45% - progress : 40% complete
extraction updated : success : 46% - progress : 41% complete
extraction updated : success : 48% - progress : 41% complete
extraction updated : success : 50% - progress : 42% complete
extraction updated : success : 50% - progress : 42% complete
extraction updated : success : 50% - progress : 42% complete
extraction updated : success : 50% - progress : 43% complete
extraction updated : success : 51% - progress : 43% complete
extraction updated : success : 51% - progress : 43% complete
extraction updated : success : 53% - progress : 45% complete
extraction updated : success : 50% - progress : 43% complete
extraction updated : success : 54% - progress : 45% complete
extraction updated : success : 53% - progress : 45% complete
extraction updated : success : 51% - progress : 45% complete
extraction updated : success : 53% - progress : 44% complete
extraction updated : success : 54% - progress : 45% complete
extraction updated : success : 53% - progress : 44% complete
extraction updated : success : 53% - progress : 45% complete
extraction updated : success : 54% - progress : 45% complete
extraction updated : success : 56% - progress : 46% complete
extraction updated : success : 56% - progress : 45% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 46% complete
extraction updated : success : 56% - progress : 45% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 47% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 47% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 47% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 47% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 47% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 47% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 48% complete
extraction updated : success : 59% - progress : 48% complete
extraction updated : success : 59% - progress : 48% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 48% complete
extraction updated : success : 58% - progress : 48% complete
extraction updated : success : 61% - progress : 48% complete
extraction updated : success : 61% - progress : 49% complete
extraction updated : success : 62% - progress : 49% complete
extraction updated : success : 61% - progress : 49% complete
extraction updated : success : 61% - progress : 49% complete
extraction updated : success : 62% - progress : 50% complete
extraction updated : success : 64% - progress : 50% complete
extraction updated : success : 64% - progress : 51% complete
extraction updated : success : 64% - progress : 51% complete
extraction updated : success : 66% - progress : 51% complete
extraction updated : success : 62% - progress : 49% complete
extraction updated : success : 66% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 66% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 66% - progress : 51% complete
extraction updated : success : 66% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 64% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 66% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 67% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 67% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 67% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 67% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 66% - progress : 52% complete
extraction updated : success : 69% - progress : 53% complete
extraction updated : success : 69% - progress : 53% complete
extraction updated : success : 69% - progress : 53% complete
extraction updated : success : 69% - progress : 54% complete
extraction updated : success : 67% - progress : 54% complete
extraction updated : success : 69% - progress : 53% complete
extraction updated : success : 69% - progress : 54% complete
extraction updated : success : 69% - progress : 53% complete
extraction updated : success : 70% - progress : 54% complete
extraction updated : success : 69% - progress : 54% complete
extraction updated : success : 70% - progress : 54% complete
extraction updated : success : 70% - progress : 54% complete
extraction updated : success : 70% - progress : 55% complete
extraction updated : success : 72% - progress : 55% complete
extraction updated : success : 72% - progress : 55% complete
extraction updated : success : 74% - progress : 56% complete
extraction updated : success : 72% - progress : 55% complete
extraction updated : success : 72% - progress : 56% complete
extraction updated : success : 74% - progress : 56% complete
extraction updated : success : 74% - progress : 56% complete
extraction updated : success : 72% - progress : 56% complete
extraction updated : success : 74% - progress : 57% complete
extraction updated : success : 75% - progress : 57% complete
extraction updated : success : 77% - progress : 57% complete
extraction updated : success : 77% - progress : 57% complete
extraction updated : success : 77% - progress : 58% complete
extraction updated : success : 75% - progress : 57% complete
extraction updated : success : 77% - progress : 58% complete
extraction updated : success : 77% - progress : 58% complete
extraction updated : success : 77% - progress : 58% complete
extraction updated : success : 79% - progress : 58% complete
extraction updated : success : 79% - progress : 58% complete
extraction updated : success : 79% - progress : 59% complete
extraction updated : success : 82% - progress : 60% complete
extraction updated : success : 87% - progress : 64% complete
extraction updated : success : 90% - progress : 65% complete
extraction updated : success : 90% - progress : 65% complete
extraction updated : success : 92% - progress : 65% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 66% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 93% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 67% complete
extraction updated : success : 95% - progress : 95% complete
extraction updated : success : 96% - progress : 99% complete
extraction updated : success : 96% - progress : 99% complete
extraction updated : success : 96% - progress : 99% complete
extraction updated : success : 100% - progress : complete`

- Why are some received calls unordered ?
- Which property best represents the progress : is it `payload.Payload.bubble.success`or `payload.Payload.bubble.progress`? (both are tracked in this log) ?
- Is there a way to know in the payload that the % at the beginning of the process corresponds to the posting of the manifest and not to the translation progress ? This is misleading.
- When posting the webhook, it would be fine if we could specify a % of progress as a step, so that for instance the call would be made each time the translation is 10% more advanced.

Thanks for your help !

Maxime

Answer (score 0):

So I will try to answer you step by step.

1. About 'duplicate callbacks', if you mean requests that came to your
   endpoint, maybe this is because of large file that you tried to
   processed. I will try to reproduce it by my self but can you also
   check first translate small file.
2. About 'bubble.success' and 'bubble.progress'. 'Success' will tell you about
   percents o file that was handled and 'Progress' will
   tell you about percents o translation that was handled.
3. About 'unordered calls'. Basically that's exactly use case for webhooks, 
   because process of translation is async. And to avoid
   possible conflicts during translation files also if problems not on
   Autodes service side but on cloud server side or caused of instable
   network connectio(slow network etc.), in all this case Webhooks help
   you create safe workflow, all that you need just check webhook.
   Payload.status.
4. About translation progress. It's all depends on file size, if Derivative Api 
   translate small file it will divide 100% of your progress on 2 and then just 
   show you 0%, 50% and 100% of progress. So then large file you will have them 
   more times whole progress will be divided on 2. One more time 
   'Payload.status' field will tell you when translation is complete and 
   'Payload.bubble.progress' will show you current translation state.
5. About Setting progress steps. I will ask about it dev team, maybe they will propose some solution.

If you want we can speak more detail, in this case please provide some samples of your hook creation code and job posting code

Comment: First of all many thanks for your explanations. What do you call a large file? My test file weighs 78 Mo and it is small compared to my other models. Regarding success/progress meanings, I think I should monitor progress. Thanks for talking to the dev team about my progress step idea.